# Junk Spark output file on S3 with dollar signs

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a simple spark job that reads a file from s3, takes five and writes back in s3.
What I see is that there is always additional file in s3, next to my output "directory", which is called output_$folder$.

What is it? How I can prevent spark from creating it?
Here is some code to show what I am doing...

```
x = spark.sparkContext.textFile("s3n://.../0000_part_00")
five = x.take(5)
five = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(five)
five.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("s3n://prod.casumo.stu/dimensions/output/")
```

After the job I have s3 "directory" called output which contains results and another s3 object called output_$folder$ which I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, it seems I found out what it is.
It is some kind of marker file, probably used for determining if the S3 directory object exists or not.
How I reached this conclusion?
First, I found this link that shows the source of

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem#mkdir
```

method: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/S3-Extra-folder-files-for-every-directory-node-td15078.html

Then I googled other source repositories to see if I am going to find different version of the method. I didn't.

At the end, I did an experiment and rerun the same spark job after I removed the s3 output directory object but left output_$folder$ file. Job failed saying that output directory already exists.

My conclusion, this is hadoop's way to know if there is a directory in s3 with given name and I will have to live with that.

All the above happens when I run the job from my local, dev machine - i.e. laptop. If I run the same job from a aws data pipeline, output_$folder$ does not get created.

Answer (score 7):

Changing S3 paths in the application from `s3://` to `s3a://` seems to have done the trick for me. The `$folder$` files are no longer getting created since I started using `s3a://`.

Answer (score 1):

`s3n://` and `s3a://` doesn't generate marker directory like `<output>_$folder$`

If you are using hadoop with AWS EMR., I found moving from `s3` to `s3n` is straight forward since they both use same file system implementation, whereas `s3a` involves AWS credential related code change.

```
('fs.s3.impl', 'com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem')
('fs.s3n.impl', 'com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem')
('fs.s3a.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')
```

Comment: s3n is obsolete and removed from recent hadoop releases. S3A does still create markers, but with a trailing /. It deletes them after adding files underneath; latest builds let you skip that delete (performance), at the cost of incompatibility.

Comment: @stevel I agree with you. Is there a way to avoid this markers in `s3` ?

Comment: S3 is EMR;s closed source FS. IF you are a customer of AWS, talk to them direct